# add two JPanels to JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add two JPanels to a Jframe, but it seems that they look like one. I'm trying tow stack them on top of each other like this image.

[image: layout image]

I thinking I may need to look at layout managers? I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

```
package projectTwo;

import javax.swing.*;

public class checkFrame 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Compose Message");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      checkPanel bob  = new checkPanel();
       //frame.add(bob);
       frame.getContentPane().add(bob);
       frame.setResizable(false);
       frame.setSize(750, 500);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

---

```
package projectTwo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class checkPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JPanel entry, display;
    private JLabel name, checkAmount, payOrderOf, numPrint, numWords;
    private JTextField nameT, checkAmountT;
    private JButton Submit;

   public checkPanel()
   {
       entryComponents();
        checkDisplay();
   }
    private void entryComponents(){

     name = new JLabel("Name:");
    checkAmount = new JLabel("Check Amount:");


    nameT = new JTextField(20);
    nameT.addActionListener(this);

    checkAmountT = new JTextField(20);
    checkAmountT.addActionListener(this);

    Submit = new JButton("Submit");
    Submit.addActionListener(this);


    add(name);
    add(nameT);
    add(checkAmount);
    add(checkAmountT);
    add(Submit);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 75));
    setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
}

private void checkDisplay(){
    payOrderOf = new JLabel("Pay to the Order of: ");


    add(payOrderOf);

    setBackground(new Color(220,255,225));
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "*I just need a little nudge in the right direction.*" A good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at layout managers. At the moment you are simply adding JPanels to each other without any specification on where they should be.

You have a few options in this case. You could use a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), but that leads to all the panels being the same size. If you just want two panels below each other, I would suggest using a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). I've adjusted your code as follows:

```
public class checkPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
private JPanel entry, display;
private JLabel name, checkAmount, payOrderOf, numPrint, numWords;
private JTextField nameT, checkAmountT;
private JButton Submit;

public checkPanel()
{
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 75));
    entryComponents();
    checkDisplay();

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(entry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
private void entryComponents(){

    entry = new JPanel();
    // You should specify entry's layout as well FlowLayout are used by default

    name = new JLabel("Name:");
    checkAmount = new JLabel("Check Amount:");


    nameT = new JTextField(20);
    nameT.addActionListener(this);

    checkAmountT = new JTextField(20);
    checkAmountT.addActionListener(this);

    Submit = new JButton("Submit");
    Submit.addActionListener(this);


    entry.add(name);
    entry.add(nameT);
    entry.add(checkAmount);
    entry.add(checkAmountT);
    entry.add(Submit);


    entry.setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
}

private void checkDisplay(){

    display = new JPanel();
    // You should specify display's layout as well FlowLayout are used by       default

    payOrderOf = new JLabel("Pay to the Order of: ");


    display.add(payOrderOf);

    display.setBackground(new Color(220,255,225));
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

It is in general a good idea to assign a layout to each JPanel you create. The choice of layout depends on how the panel should function.

Comment: // You should specify entry's layout as well FlowLayout are used by default. So I should have my code look like this sample? JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

Comment: @JamesParker yes you should. Each JPanel should have a layout defined which indicates how elements are positioned inside the panel. And then elements added to that panel using the selected layout specification. For example for a BorderLayout each element's position must be indicated eg panel.add(new JLabel(''"), BorderLayout.CENTER) whereas in a GridLayout the order is predetermined and you can simply add elements eg. panel.add(label1) and panel.add(label2). Hope this helps.

Comment: I re did the private void entryComponents() with JPanel entry = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  and change the add s look like this entry.add(name,BorderLayout.CENTER); What do I need to do in my constructor to load these?

Comment: Since entry is a class variable (private JPanel entry;), you can initialize it with entry = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) in your entryComponents() method as in my example. Then you just need to call entryComponents() from the constructor which sets up entry for you. Now you can just add entry to your class as I illustrated in checkPanel's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

using [Gridbag Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) can help you a lot I would put a separator between panels as well

Comment: Thank you for your input I will keep that in mind. We will be learning layout here soon.